# Stubborn Nav-bar not centering?

Tags: css, vbulletin

I have been trying to center a Navigation bar on my Vbulletin website for a few days now. I've tried changing the parent class, the child class, manually inserting CSS in the html element, but it seems that something is overriding the style somewhere. Firebug does not seem to identify the problem for me.

Link to the forum: http://www.mobileassaultgroup.co.uk/forum/

The navbar is just underneath the banner image.

I have tried

```
display: block-inline
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
horizontal-position: middle;
```

On both the `<ul>` and `<div>` to no avail; it just sticks there slightly off to the left.

It is not the search bar on the right hand side either as I deleted that from the page and it still stays on that position.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work if you remove the search box.

CSS:

```
#navtabs_container {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

#vbtab_forum ul {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -260px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This css of yours won't work. This this instead.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support